# check if 5 digit number is available in a string

Tags: php, search, expression

```
$st1='dsdsdsd 97537 sdsdd dsddd';
$st2='fdsf 23e  sdsd 434  432443454';
$st3='fdf97537 ds344dsddd';
```

I want to check whether a  5 digit number is available in a string.

st1-- has 5 digit number

st2--- not

st3-- has 5 digit number

Comment: What if more than one five-digits number is found?

Comment: it can have one or more 5 digit number only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple regex will do the job.

```
preg_match('/\d{5}/', $input)
```

See also http://www.php.net/preg_match

Comment: Word boundary won't match `fdf97537`.

Comment: @sachleen I just noticed that and removed my comment - added a valid answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression with `preg_match()` or `preg_match_all()`

```
preg_match("/\b[^\d]*\d{5}[^\d]*\b/", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that each element to be checked if this is five digits number is separated by space in string. Therefore you may use `explode` function to convert string into array of substrings. next you can use `is_numeric` function to check if that is digit along with check if that sub string is five length long. Also you may use regular expression for that.

Here RegEx is far more better. As I see the @Matt's answer meets these requirements, my comments will be unnecessary.

Comment: Regex is the way to go here. `explode()` combined with string length checks is too heavy.